# Get error details when using Rf_initEmbeddedR to embed R within a C++ application

Tags: r

So i was initially using `setup_Rmainloop()` for initializing the R environment embedded within a C++ project but it had some problems with saving images to the device , so i changed my code to use `Rf_initEmbeddedR(0, NULL)` and it worked fine

But now the problem is that whenever i get an error from running  a statement , i don't get the error details.

For ex , the following R script

```
x<- 2 
abc()
```

used to return the following error if i used setup_Rmainloop() :

```
Error: could not find function "abc"
```

but now with `Rf_initEmbeddedR(0, NULL)`  , i don't get the error details.

Any ideas as to how i can get the error details ?